# How to access u boot environment from linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, boot, boot-loader

How can I access and change the u-Boot env variables in linux. Using the u-boot/tools/env directory in u boot directory:

```
u-boot$ make env
```

Which created the executable file `fw_printenv`. I  copied this to /usr/sbin and on target etc/fw_env.config file:

---

```
# Configuration file for fw_(printenv/saveenv) utility.
# Up to two entries are valid, in this case the redundand
# environment sector is assumed present.
# MTD device name     Device offset    Env. size    Flash sector size
/dev/mtd0          0x00000                0x20000         0x20000
```

---

```
target#./fw_printenv
SEGV
```

What is causing this error?

#### /proc/mtd

```
dev:    size   erasesize  name                                                  
mtd0: 00020000 00020000 "flash_uboot_env"                                       
mtd1: 002e0000 00020000 "flash_linux_image"                                     
mtd2: 00900000 00020000 "flash_jffs2"                                           
mtd3: 00900000 00020000 "flash_data"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `fw_env.config` differs from mine. I have the u-boot env on the range 0x00260000-0x00280000. As I recall, the fw_env file is pretty sensitive, and if you forget some column fw_setenv will fall back to some default value which can cause all sorts of weird errors.

Just for reference, here is my fw_env.config

```
root@linux:~# cat /etc/fw_env.config 
# Dev. name    offset    env. size     flash sector size    nbr. sectors
  /dev/mtd1    0x00      0x2000        0x20000              1
```

You could cross compile `strace`and use that for troubleshooting.

Comment: Is the procedure what I am following is correct..??

fw_env.config is a file which we will creat on target /etc am I correct...??

IN my case what are value will become for offset,env.size and flash sectort size with considering my proc/mtd out...??

Comment: Yes, `fw_env.config` should be placed in `/etc` on target. It seems your `fw_env.config` is missing the column `nbr. sectors`, but apart from that it looks OK. Please try `strace` on the `fw_printenv`, this is really useful to narrow the error down. It could be that you are missing some libraries or something like that.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply...
I have using the nbr. sectors as 1 even though its giving the same error SEGV. what will be the other possibility since I am new to this please help me

Comment: should I need to change anything in the files fw_env.h and fw_env.c and fw_evn_main.c files please suggest me. I used those file as it is in u boot.in u boot I executed make env command and obtained the fw_printenv file that i copied.please help me

Comment: I don't think that you need to change the `fw_env.*`. I think should try the `strace` approach, this usually give a good indication on what is causing the problem. I've created a gist that shortly describes how to build strace on https://gist.github.com/ElektroKotte/5450136.

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion
my problem solved bye compiling with respect to processor architecture. and using correct env_size flash sector.
# MTD device name  Device offset    Env. size  Flash sector size
/dev/mtd0          0x00000    (4*1024)         0x20000